# Invalid keystore format expo react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, keystore

I'm trying to build android application via expo(react-native). My build failed couple of times with error `Invalid keystore format`. When I try to upload with automatically generated keystore by expo it works, but when I specify to my own keystore file, it fails. Extension of my keystore is `.jks`. All keys and passwords for it are correct.
What can be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember how problem was solved, but I think I had just to wait when google play store would approve my new key.